# Actionscript 3 and XML with CDATA

Tags: css, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to convert a AS2 xmas card that we have to AS3 an I am stuck with displaying XML with CDATA. Basically the HMTL tags still get ouput.

**Here is my XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<data>
  <textblock>
     <![CDATA[<h1>Seasons Greetings!</h1><p>from everyone at Honda</p>]]>
  </textblock>
</data>
</config>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    font-size:55;
    color:#333333;
}

p {
    font-size:25;
    color:#333333;
}
```

**and my AS3**:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader; 
import flash.text.StyleSheet;

var myXML:XML = new XML(); 
var XML_URL:String = "config.xml"; 
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL); 
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL); 
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded); 

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    myXML = XML(myLoader.data); 
    trace("Data loaded."); 
    blocktext.text = myXML.data.textblock;
}

var textStyleSheet:StyleSheet;
function loadCSS():void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCSSLoadComplete); 
    loader.load(new URLRequest("config.css"));
}
function onCSSLoadComplete(event:Event):void
{
    textStyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
    textStyleSheet.parseCSS(event.target.data);
    //loadXML();
}
```

It sill outputs the H1 and P html tags and doesn't use the styling.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could start with

```
blocktext.styleSheet = textStyleSheet;
blocktext.htmlText = myXML.data.textblock.children.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks. `blocktext.htmlText = myXML.data.textblock.toString();` seems to work for the HTML tags but not working with the css.

Comment: @snookian Updated my post. **StyleSheet** does not work abstractly, you need to assign one to the **TextField** you need to style.